# Bash Script: find files with data YY/MM/DAY - variable filename

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm writing a shell script that has to find files.

In particular file names are like this one: some_text_years.month.day_hour
So for each day I have 24 files, my script has to find files dated one day before.

Files to be found are in the same directory where the script.sh is located.

Therefore if today is 20/08 my script has to find all the 24 files created the day before, ie. the 19.

So my script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
base_name="some_text_"
year_mounth=`date +%Y.%m.`
today=$(date +%d)
yestarday=`expr $today - 1`
foo_variable=$base_name$year_mounth$yestarday #concatenation 
pattern="$foo_variable*"#concatenation with *
find . -name "$pattern" -exec some commands ..
```

The script does not work.. I don't understand the reason..
.. maybe the problem is the `*` operator not well interpreted by the find ?

Instead the following command line, given in terminal, works fine

```
find . -name 'some_text_2014.08.19*'
```

Example of file name:

- some_text_2014.08.19_00
- some_text_2014.08.19_01
  ...
- some_text_2014.08.19_23

No output from script.. it does not given error..

Can anyone help me ?

Please comments your answer in order to let me (and the other who read the post) understand where i do a mistake.

Please help to improve my script. Don't post any other different script solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see a space after `=` in `today= $(date +%d)`. Also, you use `yestarday` and `yetarday` (without s) for variable.

Comment: You have a typo in `foo_variable=$base_name$yetarday`. You mistyped `yesterday` as `yetarday`

Comment: Wrong logic. Imagine the date `2014.08.01` e.g. Aug.1. What will calculate the `$today -1`? `Aug.0`, instead of `July.31`... So, you cant mechanically subratct `1` from the day, for getting "yesterday"....

Comment: Corret .. i will insert an if/fi construct in order to avoid this situation.. Good Idea :) .. anyway problem is still open

Comment: :) and remember the date 2014.01.01 too, you will need to get 2013.12.31... And in some years, From `YYYY.03.01`, you need get `YYYY.02.29` or `YYYY.02.28` - depending on the year... So, instead of many (wrong) `if-fi`s - use my solution... :)

Comment: Please don't add "[SOLVED]" to your question title. The way to indicate that your question has been correctly answered is to accept an answer (by clicking the green check mark). Also, I see that you've made some changes to the code in your question. I haven't looked at the changes closely, but if you've *corrected* the code in your question, please **don't do that**; see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141749/167210) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you don't need worry about spaces and/or newlines in the filenames, so tne next simple script should done the job

```
prefix="some_"

#generate the pattern for yesterday (current_time - 86400 seconds)    
ypatt=$(date --date @$(($(date +%s) - 86400)) +"%Y.%m.%d")   #linux - gnu date
#ypatt=$(date -j -f %s $(($(date +%s) - 86400)) +"%Y.%m.%d")  #for OS X

find . -print | grep "/${prefix}${ypatt}"
```

e.g. for the next filenames:

```
some_2014.08.18_00.txt some_2014.08.19_02.txt some_2014.08.20_10.txt
some_2014.08.18_23.txt some_2014.08.19_05.txt some_2014.08.20_11.txt
```

will print

```
./some_2014.08.19_02.txt
./some_2014.08.19_05.txt
```

and the next

```
find . -print | grep "/${prefix}${ypatt}" | xargs commands -args
```

will execute `commands -args ...found_filenames...`

Comment: Please help to improve my script. Don't post any other different script solution, in order to help me to improve my script. Thanks

Comment: @Ch3bych3v simply, check other answers. This site should help OTHERS too, (with similar problems) so I provided a solution what is cleaner and better for this situation. You could (of course) accept other solutions, what are "improving" your script. (what has IMHO an wrong logic)

Comment: Ok. That's fine ... but I tried << find . -print | grep "/${pattern}" >>, i.e. your solution on my script.. but it does not work. Any idea?

Comment: @Ch3bych3v  because in my answer didn't exists `grep "/${pattern}"` but `grep "/${prefix}${ypatt}"` what is an BIG difference...

Comment: It is possible to write: `ypatt=$(date --date @$(($(date +%s) - 86400)) +"%Y.%m.%d")` and don't need the helper variable.

Comment: @jm666 : Tried againg you script. Now not gives error but the script does not give output..

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash
base_name="some_text_"
year_month=`date +%Y.%m.`
today=$(date +%d)
yesterday=`expr $today - 1`
pattern="$base_name$year_month$yesterday" #concatenation
find . -name "$pattern" -exec some commands ..
```

Try this

Comment: Ok.. i have corrected the script posted in stackoverflow.. but the script doesn't work any way..

Comment: are those files present in same directory where your script is? If they are in diff directory then instead of . put path of directory or put /

Comment: can you please paste some file names as examples?

Comment: Example file name: some_text.2014.08.19_00 some_text.2014.08.19_01 some_text.2014.08.19_03 .. so on until some_text.2014.08.19_23

Comment: Then you have to provide more information. It works great here!
Your exact script, error messages...

Answer (score -1):

I could rewrite your script as,

```
#!/bin/bash
base_name="some_text"
today=$(date +%d)
yesterday=$((today-1))
pattern="${base_name}*${yesterday}*" #concatenation
find . -name $pattern -exec ...some commands
```

output is like,

```
[root@giam39 ~]# ./temp.sh
./some_text.2014.08.19_01
```

Comment: It does not work. Please post only solution really working . Thanks

Comment: No error.. simply no output. You have inserted a * in the middle that is not usefull for my case. Please read more careffully problem text. Thanks